# iOS App Bluetooth cannot connect to peripheral device

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, bluetooth

I'm trying to connect to bluetooth printers using a third party libraries. Everything works fine on iPad, iPhone, iPod touch. Now i have 3 iPad Air devices and I always got the following error message:

```
ERROR - sock can not connect: 2
```

On all other devices, the connection works fine. Any idea, what I can do?

Same problem:

- https://discussions.apple.com/message/30117834#30117834

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of iOS is on your iPads? There seem to be some external accessory connection issues in iOS 9.3.1. They should be fixed in 9.3.2. I've tested the beta and it seems to be working as expected again.

Comment: The iPads are running 9.3.1. After update to 9.3.2 beta4 everything works fine. It's a very bad bug for our customers...

Comment: Are there any workarounds for the problem? Many of our customers are not able to work with there devices?

Comment: Not that I know of. You might be able to contact Apple directly for more info. It broke a lot of our test devices until we upgraded to 9.3.2. An Apple rep originally told us about the issue and that it is fixed in the beta. If you do find a workaround, please share it here!

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled iOS 9.3.1 with a ipsw and it worked again.
I think there may be some configure files created before iOS 9.3.1 make this bug happen.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue recently on an iPad 4 mini running iOS 11.0.3 trying to connect to a Socket Mobile scanner in MFi-SPP mode. The bluetooth connection seemed to work properly, but as soon as the Socket Mobile SDK tried to connect I also got the `ERROR - sock can not connect: 2` errors.

I ended up doing a factory restore which resolved the issue, but I never figured out what was causing it.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error with Socket Mobile scanner, on iPad Pro with iOS 11.0.3. Updating iPad to latest iOS version (11.3) resolved the issue.

At the same time, on another iPad running on iOS 11.1, it was working fine.